# Hash three 32-bit integers into a 64-bit integer?

Tags: performance, hash, integer

Looking for some ways to hash three 32-bit integers into a single 64-bit integer.  Interested in knowing a fast way of doing this but with as few collisions as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? You might use a hash function like [MumurHash3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40702815/c-murmurhash3-how-to-hash-integer) by calling it three times. If you are able to access the three integers as one array of bytes, a single call is sufficient.

Comment: Haven't tried anything yet, but thanks for the info.